# How to convert a regression model into classification model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, computer-vision

I have a regression model but I want to convert it into a classification model. Let's say between 0 to 4 "Bad" and 5 "Avg." and between 6 to 10 "Good". But I am not sure, how to do it? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Surely you've answered your own question? Can you not put some thresholds in with some `if` statements to process your output?

Comment: I agree with @jhso this is the way to go. You can set your threshold according to a metric, for example if you use a threshold of 0.6 for example your accuracy will be 30%, but with 0.8 it will be 60%.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but I want to implement over it. For that, I need to categorize the values into classes. That's why if- else statement is not suitable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you mean is that you have ordinal classes that you want to change into categorical classes. Its a bit tricky but you can do this using two different ways:

1. In your dataframe, change the labels to Bad, Average and Good using your conditions, use a LabelEncoder to encode them and train the network using softmax activation in the final layer.
2. In case you do not want to train your network again, in the predict script, add an if-elif-else condition to set the output.